# How to correct error "string was not recognized as a valid DateTime" when executing program?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

How to correct this error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"?
The error happens when trying to save the data
tried something like this with no luck as well("Checkin_Time"):

```
"this.Text="1/01/2019";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);"
```

Changed the approach to a more simplified way of sorts...

Thank you

```
  try
    {
    string thisDay1 = DateTime.Now.ToString();


    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(UpdateName);

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [IMGs] (UPC, Checkin_Time, Photo) values (?, ?, ?)", Conn);

    byte[] image_bytes = ImageToBytes(bm, ImageFormat.Png);

    OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter();
    param.OleDbType = OleDbType.Binary;
    param.ParameterName = "Image";
    param.Value = image_bytes;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    OleDbParameter param1 = new OleDbParameter();
    param1.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
    param1.ParameterName = "UPC";
    param1.Value = textBox1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

    OleDbParameter param2 = new OleDbParameter();
    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    param2.OleDbType = OleDbType.DBTime;//
    param2.ParameterName = "Checkin_Time";
    param2.Value = date;//TRIED USING THE "thisDay1" DIRECTLY & GOT SAME ERROR|FIELD IN DB IS SET AS Date/Time
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);


    // Execute the command (with no return value).
    cmd.Connection = Conn;
    Conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
    if (Conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) Conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You should move the call to _conv_photo()_ after the first two addwithvalue. Also inside that conv_photo you add the parameter to a cmd variable that is not  declared. Where is the declaration and its initialization?

Comment: @steve tried the changes but still having issues updated main post

Comment: On which line do you get that error? Something is null in your code and cannot be used to do anything until you initialize it

Comment: it is on the void conv_photo()

Answer (score 0):

Your string provider should be like this :

```
OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(@" provider=Microsoft.ace.Oledb.12.0; data source=C:\fotos\IMRDATABASE.accdb; Persist Security Info=False");
```

for more information about connection strings see [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)